# Check ipaddress with ip2long fails

Tags: php, ip-address

Hi I am attempting to check a users ipaddress that can come from two specific ranges. I convert the users ipaddress using ip2long, I then check to see if they are in range however it is failing. I wondered if anyone can spot any rookie mistakes as I am quite new to PHP. Thanks in advance:

```
$high_ip = ip2long('87.228.97.128');
$low_ip = ip2long('83.229.97.165');
$second_high_ip = ip2long('16.254.116.1');
$second_low_ip = ip2long('16.254.116.128');
$userip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);


    if($userip  <= $high_ip && $low_ip <= $userip ){
        //do something  
    }else if($userip  <= $second_high_ip && $second_low_ip <= $userip ) {
        // do something
    }else {
       // echo "invalid ip";
 }
```

-- edit -- When hitting the page from an ipaddress within the range it fails the if check as though the ipaddress is wrong.

Comment: Define "it is failing". What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Print out your 5 variables. Check if their content matches your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help I had made a rookie error :-0

Quite embarrassing lol

I had the if statement incorrectly.

should have been :

```
($userip  <= $second_high_ip && $second_low_ip >= $userip )
```